# How to call a function from an extension to UIViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios-extensions

I am trying to make my `Navigation bar` transparent. It works when i create the function within the same `ViewController` however i want to reuse it in many other `ViewControllers` so i decided to use an `extension` extending the `UINavigationController`. When i try calling the function into `ViewDidLoad`, it doesn't work.

```
import UIKit

class StudentsViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.makeNavigationBarTransparent()   
    } 
}
```

Here is my extension

```
import UIKit

extension UINavigationController {
    func makeNavigationBarTransparent() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure `self.navigationController != nil`.

Comment: @MahendraGP did you read the question?

Comment: @AshleyMills, It was just a suggestion. He also said that in other view controller doesn't work so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the on the `navigationController?.`

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func makeNavigationBarTransparent() {
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you decided to write the extension for navigation controller, you must write it from its prespective:

```
import UIKit

extension UINavigationController {
    func makeNavigationBarTransparent() {
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your viewController isn't placed in your navigation stack yet. If your vc isn't placed in navigation stack then self.navigationController will returns **nil**.

Try to move your **makeNavigationBarTransparent()** call to **viewWillAppear** method.